# Will polymer components be compatible with Angular 2.0

Tags: polymer

I am designing a suite of polymer components for finance but would like to take advantage of Angular 2.0 when it comes out, if it offers significant advantages on-top of Polymer. Can someone advise weather it is likely to be a simple process, using polymer components with Angular 2.0. Will Polymer components wrote in ES5 work well with angular 2.0 ones written in ES6?

Answer (score 0):

The plans are to make Angular 2.0 compatible with Polymer.
As far as I know Angulars ES6 will be converted to ES5 anyway so I wouldn't expect any problems.